# Auto post from joomla article to Instagram?

Tags: joomla, instagram, instagram-api, joomla-extensions

we want an auto publisher , whenever an joomla article is published, automatically publishes the article data such as title, image, description etc, on the Instagram. If this possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible with a content - plugin. You can use the `onContentAfterSave` [event](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content#onContentAfterSave) to do that.

Within this very callback you get the Article as parameter, so you can access all details of it, to create the webservice call.

There are some more [events which plugins](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events) can listen to. Joomla Plugins are pretty simple to develop, basically they consist of an describing `xml` and a `php` file and you can find documentation [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Developers#Plugins). To get started you should have a look at an existing content plugin (/plugins/content/*).

The actual call to instagram can be done using [curl](http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php).

Looking out for an Instagram api, I found that: [github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) and [instagram.com/developer](https://www.instagram.com/developer/). I hope that can help you with the webservice call.

Comment: Thanks for help @philipp . sorry i need an how to pass values to instagram api

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension in JED that will lessen your burden of coding. You can have a look at it here http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/social-web/social-display/jfbconnect . Remember thats a **Paid** **extension**.